# Galaxy Note 5 not connecting to PC

Tags: usb-connection-mode

My Galaxy note 5 is not connecting to my PC, it is charging, but never shows up on the PC. can this be fixed?

Comment: State your Android version-if it is Marshmallow, by default it goes to charging mode.

Answer (score 1):

Beeshyams is correct.  However, what is missing is how to change it to MTP mode.  So far the only way I have found is to activate developer options and scroll to USB Configuration and select MTP.  It's not sticky and you will need to set it each time you want to connect to a PC.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the supplied USB cord (Samsung) which came with the phone...

Comment: Why? What makes that cable so specific? Has it some features that deviate from the USB norm?

Comment: @Izzy Actually, it's a good suggestion. Maybe the OP is using a "USB charging" cable that doesn't have the data pins connected, instead of a real USB cable.

Comment: @DanHulme From that point, yes – but still, the data cable must not necessarily be the one that "came with the phone"; it must not even come from the same vendor. It just must be a "data cable" and not a "charging-only cable". I don't want to be picky, but as it's currently phrased, it's a bit misleading ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->storage->USB connection mode 
Connect to pc and change it

Comment: when I go to settings, storage, all i get is a list of all apps and how much space they take up. There is not USB connection mode option. Are you sure you meant to go to storage after settings? I was able to find it the way Richard Morton suggested but when I change it to MTP mode it doesn't stay at all, not even long enough to download once. It immediately flips back to charging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Settings --> MORE --> Edit Quick Settings --> Scroll way down to Storage, and select it. Then, when you plug in the USB cable, a dialog pops up *on the phone* asking if you want to allow access (um, choose "allow") I just copied a pic from my Note5 this way.

Answer (score 0):

Settings-->Developer Options --> USB config --> select * MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)